# The "blade" part of getting relationship through other table with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have 3 tables:

| user | order | status |
| --- | --- | --- |

I want from a foreach of my users to access the status the they order. So after searching I've find out that :

```
'students' => User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->with('order.status')
            ->paginate(20),
```

Apparently my relationships are working well for when I 'dd' User I see the Order relationship with the Status relationship.

But now how do I access the Status table from my `@foreach($students as $student)` on my `.blade.php` file?

I've tryed `{{ $student->orde->status->statu }}` (statu being the name of the table line I want to access) but Laravel is not happy with this.

When I do `{{ $student->order }}` I get that:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "user_id":1,
    "statu_id":1,
    "archive":0,
    "created_at":"2021-01-05T11:40:04.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2021-01-05T11:40:04.000000Z",
    "status": {
      "id":1,
      "statu":"command\u00e9",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null
    }
  }
]
```

So the thingy I want to access is there. It's just I don't know how to get it.

Comment: there are 'many' orders so which one would you be expecting to get the status for?

Comment: Start by using consistent spelling... In your question, you had `status`, `statu`, `staus`, `orde`, etc... I assume you mean `status` and `order`, but your JSON says `statu`, so I don't know...

Comment: Lagbox, I'm doing a foreach on the Users, a user can only make one order in my app so there is only one order status by user. 

Status is the table name,  on that table I have a 'statu' line. "Orde" and "Staus" are typo sorry.

Comment: How does `order` method in `User` model look like?

Comment: public function order (){
        return $this->hasOne(Order::class); 
    }